# How to simulate the selection/deselection of a text on a Canvas in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, canvas, selection, delphi-7

I want to simulate on a Canvas a selection/deselection of a text (like in a TEdit) in Delphi 7.
I use FillRect to change the background color and TextOut to draw the text.
But I need to know 4 color values for:

- unselected text;
- selected text;
- background of the unselected text;
- background of the selected text.

These values are changing when the user changes the Windows theme or edits the appearance of the windows.
For Classic theme in Windows XP the values are: clBlack, clWhite, clWhite, clNavy.
Maybe there are cl* constants for this in Delphi or maybe I have to use Api functions to get them.
Does anybody know how...?
Thank you.

Comment: You may be better using the Theme API to draw the text.

Comment: @David Heffernan I'll try this too, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Unselected:**

```
clWindow
clWindowText
```

**Selected:**

```
clHighlight
clHighlightText
```